# Consume data from pipeline

Tags: c#, powershell, pipeline

How to consume data from pipeline when writing cmdlets in C#?

For example I have two classes:

This one produces data:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "Numbers")]
public class GetNumbers : Cmdlet
{
    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        WriteObject(new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, true);
    }
}
```

And this one must consume this data:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Find, "Numbers")]
public class FindNumbers: Cmdlet
{
    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        foreach (var variable in %Input%) // Where do I get input? Any ReadRecord or something else?
        {
            if (variable % 2 == 0)
            {
                WriteObject(variable);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this way:

```
Get-Numbers | Find-Numbers
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [ValueFromPipeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.parameterattribute.valuefrompipeline%28VS.85%29.aspx) of [ParameterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms582834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Find, "Numbers")]
public class FindNumbers: Cmdlet
{
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = true)] // The data appear in this variable
    public int[] Input { get; set; }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        foreach (var variable in Input)
        {
            if (variable % 2 == 0)
            {
                WriteObject(variable);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This might also help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885349/how-to-write-a-powershell-script-that-accepts-pipeline-input

Comment: @Zasz: I do not see how your link is related to writing these cmdlets in C#?