# Powershell - avoid repeating arguments of Out-File

Tags: powershell, arguments

Is there any way to **avoid passing parameters to a function**, like "-Append $outfile" to Out-File, **every time**? I have a script which collects data from the system, something like:

```
... collect OS information ... | Out-File -Append $output
... collect local users ... | Out-File -Append $output
... collect logfile permissions ... | Out-File -Append $output
etc.
```

The last command in the pipe is most of the time `Out-File -Append $output` - can this be done more elegant? I had different ideas:

1. Create a **wrapper function** which passes the needed parameters to Out-File command - already tried, but I had problems to make it pipe-compatible
2. Write all output into a **String-Variable** and write the content at the end of all commands into the file - needs a lot of memory
3. Create something like an **Output-Writer-Object** which only receives once at initialization the necessary paramters - not tried yet

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: `&{command1;command2;command3;}|Out-File $output`

Comment: @Avshalom Is ">> $output" absolutely equivalent to "Out-File -Append $output"?

Comment: sure, i guess i thought that's what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont appear to be using a lot of arguments for this to be incredibly useful but a good suggestion would be to use [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx). I added some more parameters to illustrate how clean it can make code appear while still being functional.

```
$options = @{
    Append = $True
    FilePath = $output
    Encoding = "Unicode"
    Width = 400
}
```

Build a hastable of options and [splat](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx) the cmdlet with them

```
... collect OS information ... | Out-File  @options
... collect local users ... | Out-File  @options
... collect logfile permissions ... | Out-File @options
```

Outside of that a wrapper function (of filter if it is easier) like you suggest would be another option. [Look at the options in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885349/how-to-write-a-powershell-script-that-accepts-pipeline-input). Specifically the [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/885627/3829407)

Comment: `-Append` is switch parameter, so it will be just `$true`, and `$output` goes to first positional parameter `-FilePath`.

Comment: @PetSerAl fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [$PSDefaultParameterValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters_default_values?view=powershell-7.2) preference variable. Something like this:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{
    "Out-File:Encoding"="utf8";
    "Out-File:Append"=$true;
    "Out-File:FilePath"=$output
}
```

*This feature is especially useful when you must specify the same alternate parameter value nearly every time you use the command or when a particular parameter value is difficult to remember, such as an email server name or project GUID.*

Answer (score 0):

Or put everything inside a function or scriptblock.  Note that out-file defaults to utf16 encoding, and can mix encodings, as opposed to add-content.

```
& {
  ... collect OS information ... 
  ... collect local users ... 
  ... collect logfile permissions ... 
} | add-content $output
```