# Understanding piped output and how to work with this

Tags: powershell

I'm having problems understanding how I can work with output I create in a script.

The main cause is that for this example:

```
$Output = @()
$Output += New-Object psobject -Property @{FirstName="Harry";LastName="Potter";Age=11}
$Output += New-Object psobject -Property @{FirstName="Hermione";LastName="Granger";Age=11}
$Output += New-Object psobject -Property @{FirstName="Ron";LastName="Weasley";Age=11}
$Output += New-Object psobject -Property @{FirstName="Ginny";LastName="Weasley";Age=10}
$Output += New-Object psobject -Property @{FirstName="Albus";LastName="Dumbledore";Age=150}
$Output += New-Object psobject -Property @{FirstName="Severus";LastName="Snape";Age=40}
Write-Output $Output
```

I could take the table I've created, and pipe into a new scripts' parameter.

Say I'm creating a new script like this

```
Param(
  [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
  $in
)

Write-Output $in
```

The first script is a.ps1 and the second is named b.ps1
I want to prompt:

```
.\a.ps1 | .\b.ps1
```

And get the full table printed:

```
Age LastName                                            FirstName
--- --------                                            ---------
 11 Potter                                              Harry
 11 Granger                                             Hermione
 11 Weasley                                             Ron
 10 Weasley                                             Ginny
150 Dumbledore                                          Albus
 40 Snape                                               Severus
```

This is the output of the a.ps1 script, but if I'll pipe it to b.ps1 script, il recieve:

```
Age LastName                                            FirstName
--- --------                                            ---------
 40 Snape                                               Severus
```

I know that I'm doing something wrong, but what I want basicly is functionality similar to:

```
Get-Service | Stop-Service
```

Where the Stop-Service is an independant command that can accept parameters, but could also accept piped output from a different command and work fine as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a Powershell script that accepts pipeline input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885349/how-to-write-a-powershell-script-that-accepts-pipeline-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this.
Content of b.ps1:

```
Param( 
  [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
  $in
)
begin
{
    $all = @()
}
process
{
    $all += $in
}
end
{
    $all | % { Write-Output $_ }
}
```

Basically initializing a new array in `begin`, then regrouping all objects piped in `process`, and finally looping through the array to display its elements.

Result:

```
.\a.ps1 | .\b.ps1

Age FirstName LastName  
--- --------- --------  
11 Harry     Potter    
11 Hermione  Granger   
11 Ron       Weasley   
10 Ginny     Weasley   
150 Albus     Dumbledore
40 Severus   Snape
```