# Can't send parameters to PowerShell script using pipes

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to send parameters to the PowerShell script using pipes.

If I use standard function `5 | echo` everything is ok. But when I replace standard `echo` with my script myecho.ps1 `5 | myecho.ps1` no results are shown.

This is myecho.ps1 script.

```bsh
param([string]$str)

echo $str
```

How can I send parameters to myecho.ps1 script using pipes?

Comment: Duplicate. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885349/how-do-i-write-a-powershell-script-that-accepts-pipeline-input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify that `$str` can take value from pipeline (I also added `Mandatory` parameter here - it's not necessarily needed, but fits well into that specific script):

```bsh
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
  ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
  [string]
  $str
)
echo $str
```

Then you invoke that script and it should work (remember about `.\` before file name):

```bsh
PS> "a" |.\myecho.ps1
a
```

You can learn more about advanced parameters using `Get-Help about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters` or in it's [online version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-6).

Answer (score 3):

You can specify further attributes for the parameters in PowerShell, look at MS documentation about [Parameter Attribute Declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/cmdlet/parameter-attribute-declaration).

In your case you should set the attribute `valuefrompipeline` to `$true`.

Use this code for parameters you want to pass by pipeline.

```
param(
    [parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
    [string]$str
)
```

**NOTE** 
You can use pipeline in PowerShell by 2 ways, "ByValue" and "ByPropertyName", i recommend you to take a look [here](https://4sysops.com/archives/understanding-powershell-pipeline-parameter-binding/) to better understand the difference between them.